# How does this compile? c#

Tags: c#, compilation

```
object obj = new object[] { new object(), new object() };
```

How does this compile? It seems confusing.

Seems it should either be

```
object[] obj = new object[] { new object(), new object() };
```

or

```
object[] obj = { new object(), new object() };
```

Comment: It compiles because you can always declare a variable of type `object` and initialize it with whatever you like at the right hand side. If it is a value type it will be boxed.

Comment: Object is the void pointer of C#. It may point to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles because an "object" can be anything, therefore it can be a reference to an array of object. The code below using strings to make the distinction a little clearer, might help. So:

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>() { "aa", "bb" };
// Now we have an array of strings, albeit an empty one
string[] myStringsArray = myStrings.ToArray();
// Still a reference to myStringsArray, just held in the form of an object
object stillMyStringsArray = (object)myStringsArray;

// Get another array of strings and hold in the form of an object
string[] anotherArray = myStrings.ToArray();
object anotherArrayAsObject = (object)anotherArray;

// Store both our objects in an array of object, in the form of an object
object myStringArrays = new object[] { stillMyStringsArray, anotherArrayAsObject };

// Convert myStringArrays object back to an array of object and take the first item in the array
object myOriginalStringsArrayAsObject = ((object[])myStringArrays)[0];
// Conver that first array item back into an array of strings
string[] myOriginalStringsArray = (string[])myOriginalStringsArrayAsObject;
```

Essentially, an object can always be a reference to anything, even an array of object. Object doesn't care what is put in it, so by the very end of the code there, we've got a string array back. Run that code up in Visual Studio, drop a few breakpoints in and follow it through. It'll hopefully help you make sense of why the code you specified is valid =)

Answer (score 6):

object is the base for everything.  *Anything* can be assigned to a variable of type object.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
object obj = new object[] { ...}
```

The right hand part does yield a reference of type `object[]` but that type, like any other type, is assignment-compatible with `object`.

Answer (score 1):

object obj = ... here may refer to a Collection. It's not said that the difference usage of 'object' here refers to the same type of object.

Answer (score 1):

An array of objects is an object, but this is indeed weird.

Comment: Doesn't seem weird at all to me. It's C#